# Delete bulk data from MySQL table

Tags: php, mysql

I have a MySQL database table which has more than 250000 of records. Now I like to delete around 230000 records under specific condition. When I am trying to do this, I am not able to achieve it by anyway since it is completely loading for all the time.

I have tried by writing PHP script to read the data one by one and delete it. Also I tried to take the back up of the data to try by dropping the table. But I am not able to take the backup.  Also I tried to re-index, that also didn't work.

I got totally stuck up with this issue and couldn't find any way to fix.

Please anyone help me if you know any way to sort this out.

Thanks a lot,
Ram

Comment: Ram - you have to be a little more specific. What table needs emptied? What fields discriminate how it is being filtered? We can't help you clean up a table if we don't even know what the table looks like.

Comment: Maybe it would be better to select the "surviving" data into a temp table, drop the old one and then replace it by the temp table.

Comment: Why can't you write a delete sql statement?

Comment: Actually My table is Participants table which has the list of Participants for every Event. So the table structure is,

ParticipantID PRIMARY KEY,
EventID,
ParticipantName,
etc

Mistakenly there are lot of duplicate Participants(More than 200000) entered for the last event which has the ID 180. Now I want to delete all these mistakenly inserted rows. So the delete statement would be like below,

DELETE FROM tParticipator WHERE EventID = 180

I am trying to execute this in PHPMyAdmin. But it is executing infinitely.

Comment: `truncate table tablename;` will clear the whole table almost instantly.

Comment: I want remaining data from the other events. So I cannot truncate it.

Comment: Is the table indexed on EventID? If not try adding an index and then execute the query again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to index the table on the fields that you have in your WHERE conditions. In your example:

```
DELETE FROM Participator WHERE EventID = 180;
```

The index should be on EventID. Add the index with the following statement:

```
ALTER TABLE Participator add index(EventID);
```

You can find more info about mysql indexes and how to use them here:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-indexes.html

Comment: I have already tried to Index that column. But that also executing infinitely without any success.

Comment: Define infinitely? Its normal for adding an index to a large table to take more than a 5-10 minutes, especially if the mysql server does not have a lot of hardware resources, or it is busy executing other queries

Comment: It is running for hours but still not completing the execution.

Comment: Hmm... Can you put the create table statement in the for in your question: 
SHOW CREATE TABLE Participator;

Comment: CREATE TABLE tbl_participator (
  participator_id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  event_id int(11) NOT NULL,
  player_id int(11) NOT NULL,
  division_id int(11) NOT NULL,
  weight_class_id int(11) NOT NULL,
  actual_weight int(11) NOT NULL,
  user_id int(11) NOT NULL,
  registered_on date NOT NULL,
  status enum('0','1') NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  registration_id int(11) NOT NULL,
  paid_status varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (participator_id),
  KEY player_id (player_id, weight_class_id, actual_weight)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

Comment: I am trying to remove index player_id as it is not useful and I am trying to Index the column event_id. But that is also not executing successfully.